# Can I use the Mono implementation of SqlClient in MS.Net framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, sqlclient

We are testing some options to solve performance issues with .Net 4.0 SqlClient (lots of GC and finalizers, etc.) and were thinking of using a different Sql client implementation - Mono came to mind.

1) Is it possible to use the Mono implementation of SqlClient with a MS.Net application? if so- how?
2) Is the Mono implementation "stable"? which version is most recommended?
3) Does the mono implementation of SqlCommand, QueryResults, etc. contain finalizers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are seeing these impact GC, then that *suggests* you *aren't using them properly*. Of these, `SqlDataReader` doesn't have a finalizer in the first place, so I assume we're talking about `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`. Both of these inherit from `Component`, and in both cases the `Dispose()` call *unregisters* them from GC - it is:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

So: if you are setting these appear as finalizers in GC, look to see whether you are disposing your objects correctly. The easiest way to do that is via `using` statements. For example:

```
using(var conn = OpenSomeConnection())
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    // TODO configure command

    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        // TODO consume data
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the usage of unmanaged resources? do you know if the Sql connection is implemented purely in managed code?

Comment: @Amit I do not know without checking. Although I am tempted to write a pure managed TDS parser just for fun. But again: dispose deals with this. So if you are seeing too much time in Finalise, it suggests you aren't disposing. What makes you think finalise it a problem here?

Comment: Profiling and looking at perfmon indicates that when many queries are performed that process spends a lot of time in GC and the 'promoted to finilizer'/'finalization survivers' counters skyrocket

Comment: @AmitBens k; that's a start, but again: if you dispose them: **they will not be promoted to finalization**. Correct disposal avoids that. What flavor of tools are you using for data access?

Comment: Fair enough! You were right, SqlCommand objects were not disposed, I have opted to reuse the same command objects too (seems to be working just fine)